# AngularJS function () vs function factory() in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In angular I've seen directives written both as:

```
.directive('example', function () {
    // Code
});

.directive('example', function factory() {
    // Code
})
```

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: No difference at all. It is also not related to AngularJS. JavaScript supports both syntaxes (the latter declares the function with  a name and then assigns it to a variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is just passing in a named function rather then an anonymous one.

the same way as you can write functions as below:

```
var foo = function() {
    //function content
}
```

or

```
var foo = function foo() {
    //function content
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`function(){..}` is an anonymous function.

`function foo(){..}` is a named function.

There is no difference, otherwise, in functionality. Named functions are better for debugging purposes.